# Javascript - catching error if json key does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, error-handling

I'm trying catch the error for when a certain key doesn't exist in json from an API, in this case imageLinks.thumbnail.

This is what I wrote so far but I still get TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined.

```
            let cover;
            if(results.imageLinks === undefined){

                let cover = "http://actar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/nocover.jpg";

            } else {
                let cover = results.imageLinks.thumbnail;
            };
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: This is very little information to debug do u mind adding what is `results` and what does it contain? and I don't get it why are using `let cover` in 3 different places because every time u do it it makes new variable if u want to use same variable just define it once and use it.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that error on that line? Anywhere else you reference it? NB: this question has little to do with getting JSON from an API. You are dealing with JavaScript objects, not JSON.

Comment: If `results.imageLinks` is undefined, it will never execute the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator

```
if('imageLinks' in results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
(function() {
  let cover;
  const result = {
    imageLinks: {}
  };
  if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(result, 'imageLinks')) {
    return;
  }
  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(result.imageLinks, 'thumbnail')) {
    cover = results.imageLinks.thumbnail;
  } else {
    cover = "http://actar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/nocover.jpg";
  }
  console.log(cover);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little ambiguous.
I will try to answer based on what I understand from your code.
It seems you have an object called results which may or may not have a property imageLinks.
So you need to place a check "if results have property imageLinks assign cover to results.imageLinks.thumbnail otherwise assign "http://actar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/nocover.jpg"

```
let cover = results['imageLinks']['thumbnail'] ? results['imageLinks']['thumbnail'] : "http://actar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/nocover.jpg";
```

Please note that the check I have placed is more comprehensive. It will only pass if the structure of object is `{'results'  : 'imageLinks': {'thumbnail' : 'some value'}}`
 If you wish to check only for 'imageLinks' replace results`['imageLinks']['thumbnail']` with `results['imageLinks']`
In JS in you wish to check for a key in an object you can directly write `if(results['imageLinks'])`.